# convert curl command to invoke-WebRequest or Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell, curl, sonarqube, invoke-command

I have a requirement to convert a working curl command to Invoke-WebRequest command
The command is used to create a project in SonarQube

Curl:

```
curl -u as123123112312: -X POST "http://sonarqube.it.company.net:9000/api/projects/create?key=%project_key%&name=%project_name%" > NUL
```

the command I tried:

```
$e = @{
    Uri     = "http://sonarqube.it.company.net:9000/api/projects/create?key=%project_key%&name=%project_name%"
    Headers = @{"Authorization" = "Token as123123112312"}
}
Invoke-WebRequest @e -Method POST
```

Error:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized
```

Does anyone have an idea of converting curl to invoke-webrequest

Comment: try to send the Authorization header with the `Body` instead of the `Headers` parameter

Comment: did you mean like this $e = @{
    Uri     = "http://sonarqube.it.company.net:9000/api/projects/create?key=%project_key%&name=%project_name%"
    Body = @{"Authorization" = "Token as123123112312"}
} ; I tried this and still showing same error

Answer (score -1):

This has been asked before. When you are posting, you need to have a body to send too, example:

```
$username = "as123123112312";
$password = "blah";
$Bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("$username`:$password");
$encodedCredentials = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes);
$body = "your content (i.e. json here)";
Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Body $body -Headers @{ "Authorization" = "Basic " + $encodedCredentials} -Uri "http://sonarqube.it.company.net:9000/api/projects/create?key=%project_key%&name=%project_name%"
```

Comment: No, it's not working, getting the name error. "as123123112312" is not the username. It's a user token to invoke sonarqube webservices

Comment: It seems apart from Powershell you don't understand how to use curl either. In your question you specify your curl command "curl -u as123123112312: ", that is a username:password authentication translated to exactly what I pasted in Powershell.

Comment: yeah could be and I don't have much knowledge in curl.. anyway the "as12..." is the token I generated from sonarqube and when used with the curl command in a linux shell script it worked. My requirement is create a similar script in powershell. I've been looking for a solution last whole day and couldn't find any, that is why I asked the question here.